# Map function returns the same result on all buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am tyring to map an object that looks like this:

```
['note_title_test', 'note_title_test2', 'note_title_test32', 'note_title_test232', 'test title', 'testing1']
```

Here is my map function:

```
           {results.map((note, idx) => {
                    console.log(results);
                    return(
                        <Grid container spacing={0}>
                            <Grid item sm={11} md={11} lg={11}>
                            <ListItemButton className={classes.list} key={idx} onClick={(idx) => handleList(note, idx)} selectedindex={idx}>
                                <ListItemText key={idx} primary={note} secondary="date"/>
                            </ListItemButton> 
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid key={idx} item sm={1} md={1} lg={1}>
                                <IconButton
                                className={classes.tagButton}
                                onClick={handleClick}
                                aria-controls="basic-menu"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded={open ? open : undefined}
                                >
                                        <LabelIcon className={classes.listTag}/>
                                </IconButton>
                                <Menu
                                id={idx}
                                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                open={open}
                                onClose={handleClose}
                                MenuListProps={{
                                    'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                                }}
                                >
                                    <MenuItem id={idx} onClick={() => changeLabel(note, "#00AF54")}>
                                        <Box sx={{ width: "2vh", height: "2vh", backgroundColor: "#00AF54"}}
                                        >
                                        </Box>
                                        <p>green</p>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </Menu>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
```

When I click on the MenuItem, the desired outcome is just logging the correct note title, however, every MenuItem outputs the last item in the object ('testing1') instead of the item that I am clicking on.

I've gone over my code all morning but haven't been able to figure out. Am I missing something?

Comment: key is missing in menuItem `<MenuItem id={idx} key={idx} onClick={() => changeLabel(note, "#00AF54")}>` maybe thats an issue. let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491363/why-is-only-the-last-item-in-a-map-function-being-changed-in-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I didn't pass the note to the handleClick function, so it always opened menu for the same item, which was the last item in the list.

Before:

```
                                <IconButton
                                className={classes.tagButton}
                                onClick={handleClick}
                                aria-controls="basic-menu"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded={open ? open : undefined}
                                >
```

After:

```
                                    <IconButton
                                className={classes.tagButton}
                                onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, note)}
                                aria-controls="basic-menu"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded={open ? open : undefined}
                                >
```

And the handleClick function now looks like this:

```
    const handleClick = (event, note) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    setNoteTitle(note)
};
```

And the